# ESC key safari issue

Tags: javascript

Is there a better way to redo the following code below? A better approach? When the user hits the ESC key I need the page to redirect them back to their homepage (dashboard screen).

I'm having an issue with the Safari browser though. When a user in Safari hits the ESC key - my server is blocking their IP address (kinda like a brute force protection flag) and I think it's because it's trying to refresh the page over and over again without sending the person back to their dashboard.

The code below works great in Chrome and Firefox...

```
var keyPressed = {};

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  keyPressed[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  keyPressed[e.keyCode] = false;
}, false);

function goToControls() {
  if (keyPressed["27"]) {
    window.location.href = 'home.php';
  }

  setTimeout(goToControls, 5);
}

goToControls();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following and it's seems to be happy now!

```
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var isEscape = false;
    if ("key" in evt) {
        isEscape = (evt.key == "Escape" || evt.key == "Esc");
    } else {
        isEscape = (evt.keyCode == 27);
    }
    if (isEscape) {
        alert("Escape");
    }
};
```